# sql code for combining both count

Tags: sql

i have this sql code already been executing the amount of count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM a_children c 
LEFT JOIN recipient r ON c.hp_id = r.hp_id 
WHERE c.FIRST_HEALTH='OKU' 
AND c.hp_id = r.hp_id
 UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM recipient 
WHERE DISABILITY = "YES"
```

and i get the result of

```
total|
------
52   |
53   |
```

how to i combine this 2 total into one like this in the final result

```
total|
------
105  |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as a Derived Table then Sum.

```
   Select sum(total) sumofTotal from
   (SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM a_children c 
    LEFT JOIN recipient r ON c.hp_id = r.hp_id 
    WHERE c.FIRST_HEALTH='OKU' 
    AND c.hp_id = r.hp_id
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM recipient 
    WHERE DISABILITY = 'YES'
   ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE.

```
;with cte as(
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM a_children c 
LEFT JOIN recipient r ON c.hp_id = r.hp_id 
WHERE c.FIRST_HEALTH='OKU' 
AND c.hp_id = r.hp_id
 UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM recipient 
WHERE DISABILITY = "YES"

)select sum(total) as total from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is a subquery:

```
select sum(total)
from (SELECT COUNT(*) as total
      FROM a_children c LEFT JOIN
           recipient r
           ON c.hp_id = r.hp_id 
      WHERE c.FIRST_HEALTH = 'OKU' AND c.hp_id = r.hp_id
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM recipient 
      WHERE DISABILITY = 'YES'
     ) x;
```

It might be possible to simply the query further -- getting rid of the `union` entirely.  But without better knowledge of what the tables look like, it is hard to make concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
SELECT    count(sum)  AS  total 
    FROM
        (    SELECT count(*)   AS sum 
             FROM a_children c 
             LEFT JOIN recipient r ON c.hp_id = r.hp_id 
             WHERE c.FIRST_HEALTH='OKU' 
             AND c.hp_id = r.hp_id
          UNION ALL 
             SELECT count(*)  AS sum
             FROM recipient 
             WHERE DISABILITY = "YES"
        )
```